# When are closures allocated and compiled in Node.js V8?

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, v8

Based on my current assumptions about VM's and their behavior, I figure closures are allocated and compiled every time their definition is hit; in contrast to functions declared outside closures which are allocated and compiled once (because they are placed somewhere their definition is only hit once). Is this assumption correct?

So if I have a closure in `socket.on('data', function (data) {...})`, V8 allocates new memory (and possibly re-compiles) the closure *every time* data is received by the socket?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I figure closures are allocated and compiled every time their definition is hit

Not really. Closures are compiled *once*, but allocated *every time* their definition is hit. Most importantly, you have to distinguish allocation and compilation.

- Every function's code (i.e. with same place in the source code) is only compiled once, even if the function is instantiated multiple times in different environments.
  It would be pointless to compile on every instantiation, just like it is pointless to compile for every single call (though, that's literally what an "interpreter" does, and the boundaries are fluid, e.g. for lazy compilation that happens not before the time of the first call).
  Code might be compiled again (with a slower but more sophisticated compiler) if it becomes an optimisation candidate, or if the optimisation failed and it has to be deoptimised; but that's besides the point.
- Every function is allocated/instantiated when its definition is hit, which is particularly relevant for local functions (nested in other functions).
  The cost of allocation for non-closure functions is zero however, as no environment pointer needs to be stored an no instance object is needed.

> So if I have a closure in `socket.on('data', function (data) {...})`, V8 allocates new memory (and possibly re-compiles) the closure every time data is received by the socket?

Not the `function (data) {…}`, it is instantiated only once and passed to the `on` call.

But yes, if you've got a closure that is instantiated in the `…` part, then that will allocate some memory every time data is received and the handler is called. But there's no need to worry about this, memory allocation is cheap and fast.

If you are looking for technical details, I recommend to read http://mrale.ph/blog/2012/09/23/grokking-v8-closures-for-fun.html (even though it's already a few years old).

Comment: Really technical answer. Thanks for the reply. I've edited your post to add a summary. Please see if you are ok with it..

Comment: And can you clarify what "different environments" mean? Do you mean if the same module is called by multiple other modules? And you said there was a caveat: optimisation candidates are compiled many times. What qualifies as an "optimisation candidate"?

Comment: @Geotarget: A *lexical* environment, the scope of the function, i.e. the thing that the closure closes over. The thing that needs to be allocated in the heap (contrary to the stack as usual for non-closed-over environments) and that the closure needs to remember.

Comment: @Geotarget: Optimisation happens at implementation-dependent times in implementation-dependent cases, usually if a function was called very often, so that the engine figures out it is worthy for (costly) optimisation so that it runs faster in the future: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation. This doesn't matter in the context of your question however, it's the same for closures and non-closures.

Answer (score 2):

> > Based on my current assumptions about VM's and their behavior, I figure closures are allocated and compiled every time their definition is hit;

right

> > in contrast to functions declared outside closures which are allocated and compiled once.

false, these are also compiled every time their definition is hit, but they are usually put at a place, where their definition is only hit once.
Closures are designed to be defined multiple times and enclose each time different variables/values.
That's how we differentiatte wether this is a simple/anonymous function or a closure

> > V8 allocates new memory every time data is received by the socket

no, this anonymous function is compiled once, and then passed to the event-handler. The event-handler now has a reference to this function and calls it every time data is received.

The definition in this example is also hit only once, when adding the event-listener.